# UIButton background Image in IOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7, uibutton

I am setting my background image for `UIButton`, it's working fine for iOS6 but for highlighted state in iOS7 not working.

```
[clearButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-over@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[clearButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn@2x~ipad.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rana Anees: Please restart your simulator ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Remove `@2x` from the image name and keep two copies of image in your resource folder such as `back-over.png` and `back-over@2x.png` for retina and non retina devices.

Then update you code as below,

```
[clearButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-over.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Don't worry about the `@2x` images. It will automatically append the file-name with `@2x`, if the device display is Retina.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the Type of the UIButton is Custom, rather than System.

Comment: Button is of Custom type

Answer (score 0):

You only need to mention the name of the image if it's in .png format.

Example, if you have 2 images for non-retina and retina displays : `img.png` and `img@2x.png`
You only need the following to set the image:

```
[yourButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The OS automatically searches for the image and it's @2x version depending on the `scale` of the screen (Retina devices have scale 2, and non-retina have 1).

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that clearButton is declared in the .h?

Open the assistant editor, drag the button to the .h file and name it clearButton.

Now just substitute in the .m clearButton for _clearButton like this:

```
[_clearButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-over@2x.png"]    forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[_clearButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn@2x~ipad.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I just tried it with 2 images and it worked perfectly.

Also make sure that the images are imported.